# How to redirect all pages to a single page except one page without infinite loop

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Using htaccess on my WordPress site, I wish to redirect all my pages to an 
"under construction" page except for one page, www.mydomain.com/notredirect.

How do I do the above without an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

These **RewriteCond** are used to check whether the request uri is starting with `/maintenance` and `/notredirect`. `!` is negation. The **RewriteCond** is **proceeded** if uri **is not** starting with `/maintenance` and `/notredirect`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?maintenance$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?notredirect$
```

If the above **RewriteCond** are fulfilled, the following **RewriteRule** can be used to redirect user to specific page, for example, `/maintenance`.

```
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance [R, L]
```